# DS-5 edition to develop and debug Android Apps with Arm 64-bit and 32-bit native libraries

Tags: android, arm, ds-5

I am planning to develop and debug an Android App with ARM 32-bit and 64-bit native code. I believe ARM DS-5 can be used. But I am confused about which edition of DS-5 supports both ARM 64-bit and 32-bit native libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [edition comparison](http://ds.arm.com/ds-5/compare-ds-5-editions/) could perhaps be a little clearer, but the "ARMv8-A" under "processor support" really does mean that only the Ultimate edition has 64-bit support in the debugger. Similarly if you want to use the armcc toolchain then you need version 6 and the Ultimate license to compile 64-bit code. As you might expect, such restrictions don't apply to compiling with GCC.